# KeyError when getting last value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The pandas dataframe in the code below can call any value, example `q_data.low[0],q_data.date[8]` but can't call from last like `q_data.low[-1]`.

```
url = 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/AAPL/chart/1y'
q_data = pd.read_json(url)
data =  q_data.date[0]
data1 = q_data.date[-1]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vinus/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 601, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/home/vinus/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2477, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 98, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/_libs/index.c:4
404)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 106, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/_libs/index.c:
4087)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:51
26)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 759, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
 (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:14031)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 765, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
 (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:13975)
KeyError: -1
```

what is wrong with the code? How to get the last value in dataframe?

Comment: `q_data.date[len(q_data)-1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) because `date[-1]` looking for index with `-1` which does not exist, so error is raised:

```
data1 =  q_data.date.iloc[-1]
print (data1)
2018-05-11 00:00:00
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of `date` column:

```
data1 = q_data.iloc[-1, q_data.columns.get_loc('date')]
print (data1)
2018-05-11 00:00:00
```